Gradle Task Execution
In my build.gradle I define a task.
task("myTask") {
    println("Execute my task.")
    doLast {
        println("myTask is finished")
    }
}

I want to conditional execution, so in the afterEvaluate I included an onlyIf statement.  Here the conditional is static, but will be dynamic.
afterEvaluate {
    println("Executing afterEvaluate")
    tasks.getByName("myTask").onlyIf { true }
}

When I run this, 'myTask is finished' will never execute, but I will see 'Execute my task.'  Further more, in the log I never see:
 > Task myTask printed out, which seems to be standard for every other task that is ran.
What am I missing?

Review the Build Lifecycle documentation.
Your print statement will execute regardless of whether the task is currently being executed or not because it is not part of the task execution.
Move the print statement into either the doFirst { } or doLast { } block to make it part of the execution phase.

With @Cisco's comment I started to dig more into the lifecycle of Gradle.  After digging in a bit, I found afterEvaluate - Adds a closure to call immediately after this project is evaluated. This is too late in the lifecycle to modify the executing tasks.
What I wanted to do was conditionally execute a tasks provided by a plugin after the 'build' task had completed.  In case anyone else is interested, here is the process.
Step 1: Update the task I want to conditionally run to be conditional.
tasks.getByName("artifactoryPublish").onlyIf {
    properties["isPublishingEnabled"].toString().toBooleanStrict()
}

This will check the isPublishingEnabled property, and run the artifactoryPublish task only if the property is true.
Step 2: Attach it to the build.
tasks.getByName("build").finalizedBy("artifactoryPublish")

This directs tells gradle to run artifactoryPublish once build completes.
I had inherited the afterEvaluate block, and I have no idea why it was included. So, if anyone can explain how it could assist in this scenario, I would appreciate it.
